# Can't use search on a mapped object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a user component that displays a material-ui table:

[image]

The problem is, the search bar is not working for the users that are mapped by an api, but it works on the hard coded user that I inserted ("Zerya").

Here is my component code:

```
export default function User({ data })  {

  const style = styles();
  const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
  };

    const userList = data.map((row)=>{

         return (row);

     });

     console.log(userList)

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name'},
      { title: 'Details', field: 'details'},

    ],
    users:[
      {name:
          <List>
             {data.map(cn => (
               <ListItem key={cn}>
               <ListItemIcon>
                 <PeopleIcon  style={{ color: "#679eec"}} />
                </ListItemIcon>
                   <ListItemText>{cn}</ListItemText>
                </ListItem>
                 ))}
          </List>,
     details:
          <List  >
             {data.map(cn => (
            <ListItem  key ={cn}style={{ padding:" 10px"}}>
               <Link
                 to={`/users/${cn}`}>
                 <ListAltIcon  style={{ color: "#679eec"}}/>
               </Link>
            </ListItem>
                 ))}
          </List>,

    },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', details: 'Baran'},
  ],
 });

    function FormRow() {
     return (
         <div>
           <MaterialTable
             icons={tableIcons}
             title= {<h1>Users</h1>}
             columns={state.columns}
             data={state.users}
             options={{
                  search: true
                }}
           />
         </div>
     )
 }

    return (
      <div className={style.root}>
          <FormRow />
      </div>
    )
 }
```

The link for the material-ui:  https://material-ui.com/pt/components/tables/

The link for the docs, more specific info here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/search

Updated:
I console.log the state and it's very different from the hardcoded dict that i inserted there.

```
name: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: {…}, key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}

name: "Zerya Betül"
```

but i don't have a clue how to make my api data look like that on the state.

My api data comes like this:

```
Array(3)0: "Philip J. Fry"
        1: "Turanga Leela"
        2: "Bender Bending Rodríguez"
        length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: You can see in your picture that the api and hardcoded data look different.. Are you sure your entire object for users is formatted in the way you expect?  console log your state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue you are running into is that for the data from the API, you are specifying the search fields (name and details) as React components instead of strings. I've never used material-table but it probably requires the fields to be strings, and that's why it works on the hardcoded one.

If you want to customize how each column looks, it looks like you can use the `render` property for columns. When you use the `render` property, it will provide you with the data for that column. I don't think it will be a list, so in the example below I won't use the `<List>` component (which I don't think you need in this case). This is also assuming that the `data` array that comes back is your list of names.

```js
// Turn the API data into an array of objects. The <MaterialTable> component is 
// expecting an array for the data property. Each item in this array represents 
// a row in the table. You have two columns: name and details. That's what each
// of these object properties represent. 
const userList = data.map((row) => {
  return { name: row, details: row };
});

const [state, setState] = React.useState({
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', 
      field: 'name', 
      // render is a property provided by material-table. It allows you to
      // customize how each cell for a column looks. In this case, we are 
      // adding an icon. rowData is an object in the array that is supplied to
      // the data property in the <MaterialTable> component. In this case, it 
      // is state.userList. <Fragment> is a component provided by React that
      // allows you to return multiple children without having to put other and 
      // unnecessary components to the DOM.
      render: rowData => (
        <Fragment>
          <PeopleIcon  style={{ color: "#679eec"}} />
          {rowData.name}
        </Fragment>
      )
    },
    { 
      title: 'Details', 
      field: 'details',
      render: rowData => (
        <Link to={`/users/${rowData.details}`}>
          <ListAltIcon  style={{ color: "#679eec"}} />
        </Link>
      )
    },
  ],
  users: [
    // this is called 'spread'. it basically means take everything out of 
    // the userList array and put it at the front of this one. 
    ...userList,
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', details: 'Baran'},
  ]
});
```

Comment: Still looking to your code to try to understand it, but i just try it and works :)

Comment: I'll add some comments to see if that helps.